# Yocto 1.6 no libboost_log in toolchain

Tags: boost, boost-log, boost-logging, yocto

I've installed Yocto 1.6 and run the bitbake to set up the toolchain, following the tutorial written by Daiane Angolini.   While I see most of the boost libraries under $SDKTARGETSYSROOT/usr/lib, there seems to be no libboost_log.a nor libboost_log_setup.a.   I believe these were introduced with Boost 1.55, and that Yocto 1.6 has moved to Boost 1.55.  Shouldn't they be there, or have I done something wrong?

My  .../fsl-community-bsp/build/conf/local.conf:

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS ?= "${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j ${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
MACHINE ??= 'imx6qsabresd'
DISTRO ?= 'poky'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks tools-sdk"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K" 
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qemu-native = "sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-nativesdk-qemu = "sdl"
ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl-native"
CONF_VERSION = "1"

BB_NUMBER_THREADS = '1'
PARALLEL_MAKE = '-j 1'

DL_DIR ?= "${BSPDIR}/downloads/"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = ""


CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "boost"
```

Answer (score 5):

The right way is to extend the existing recipe. In fact, you normally never change a 3rd-party recipe directly. This means, you are creating your own "recipes-support/boost/" folder which includes a file called "boost_%.bbappend".
 '%' means that the boost version is not of interest. 'bbappend' means that you extend the existing boost-recipe. This file contains only one line:

```
 BOOST_LIBS += " log"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add log library you should edit boost recipe file.
In [this](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-support/boost/) example you should edit boost.inc. 
To add log, atomic and loace libraries, replace

`BOOST_LIBS = "\
    date_time \
    filesystem \
    graph \
    iostreams \
    program_options \
    regex \
    serialization \
    signals \
    system \
    test \
    thread \
    "`

with

```
BOOST_LIBS = "\
date_time \
filesystem \
graph \
iostreams \
program_options \
regex \
serialization \
signals \
system \
test \
thread \
log \
atomic \
locale
"
```

Comment: This is not how you do it. See my answer